# Почему не могу получить юзера из модуля в laravel 5.5?

Tags: auth, модули, users, laravel5

Сейчас начинаю писать на laravel. Решил создать админку моделем по этому туториалу 
https://web-programming.com.ua/realizaciya-modulnoj-struktury-v-laravel/

Все заработало, только не молу получить пользователя используя 
$request->user() или же Auth::user(), оба метода возвращают null.

В HomeController в папке app/controllers все работает, а для контроллера в модуле - нет. Подскажите почему так и как это исправить?

Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В группу роутов нужно добавить middleware web

Answer (score 0):

В laravel 5.3 > вы не можете получить доступ к сеансу или к авторизованому пользоветелю потому что middlware еще не запущен. Для этих целей используйте вот это в своем конструкторе:

```
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->user = Auth::user();
        return $next($request);
    });
```